# sbt with intellij: debug mode doesnt work

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to debug a sbt application in intellij, but somehow break points are not hit.
My steps:

On terminal, run:

> sbt -jvm-debug 5005

Then create debug configuration:

[image]

Then hit debug button:

[image]

And finally run the app:

sbt:raptor> run

Application does run well, but none of the debug points are hit.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If it remains on the latest version of the IDE, please submit the issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL .